# importar BD en powershell

Tags: powershell

actualmente debo importar las base de datos individualmente con esta parte del script

```
> Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\..\util\utilConnection.ps1; Import-Module
> $PSScriptRoot\..\util\utilDate.ps1;
> #Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\..\logging\Logging_Functions.ps1; Import-Module AzureRM.sql
> 
> $TIMESTAMP = getTimeStamp;
> 
> 
> 
> #Login-AzureRmAccount loginRMAccount;
> 
> #Set subscription Azure setSubscriptionAzureeITTS;
> 
> Write-Output "";
> 
> $myPasswordDB = ConvertTo-SecureString $SQL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_QA
> -AsPlainText -Force; $myCredentialDB = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($SQL_ACCOUNT_NAME_QA,
> $myPasswordDB); $sqlCredential = Get-Credential -Credential
> $myCredentialDB;
> 
> $resourceGroup = "resGroupDB"; $serverName = "domserverqa"; $database
> = "(2017-09-11-09:00)dbdom_temuco"; $primarykey = $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BACKUP_KEY; $StorageUri =
> "https://strdatabasebackup.blob.core.windows.net/strdatabasebackupblob/(2017-09-11-09:00)dbdom_temuco.bacpac";
> 
> 
> $importRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport –ResourceGroupName
> $resourceGroup –ServerName $serverName –DatabaseName $database
> –StorageKeytype StorageAccessKey –StorageKey $primarykey -StorageUri
> $StorageUri -AdministratorLogin $sqlCredential.UserName
> –AdministratorLoginPassword $sqlCredential.Password –Edition Basic
> –ServiceObjectiveName basic -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes 2147483648 # 2GB ->
> 2 * 1024 MB -> 2 * 1024 * 1024 KB -> 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 Bytes
> 
> $importStatus = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus
> -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink;
> 
> while ($importStatus.Status -eq "InProgress") {
>     $importStatus = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink;        
>     Write-Output ".";
>     [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(2000);             }
```

"(2017-09-11-09:00)dbdom_temuco" este dato debo modificar diariamente la fecha y dbdom_"nombre" cambiarlo dependiente la base de datos que estoy importando.

"https://strdatabasebackup.blob.core.windows.net/strdatabasebackupblob/(2017-09-11-09:00)dbdom_temuco.bacpac"; y aqui tambien debo cambiar el nombre temuco por otra base de datos.

existe alguna manera de poner todas las bases de datos juntas y que se importen todas sin tener que hacer manualmente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fue solucionado  al final utilice un array y un foreach

```
DB_NAME_MIRROR = "mirroring_<X>(<Y>)";

$primarykey = $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BACKUP_KEY; #strdatabasebackup

$STORAGE_URI_BACKUP = "https://strdatabasebackup.blob.core.windows.net/strdatabasebackupblob/(<Y>)<X>.bacpac";

#Arrays
$DB_ARRAY = @("dbdom_buin", "dbdom_elquisco", "dbdom_imelbosque", "dbdom_macul", "dbdom_lareina", "dbdom_mpinto", "dbdom_penalolen", "dbdom_coquimbo");

#Replace timestamp
$DB_NAME_MIRROR = $DB_NAME_MIRROR.Replace('<Y>',$TIMESTAMP);
$STORAGE_URI_BACKUP = $STORAGE_URI_BACKUP.Replace('<Y>',$TIMESTAMP);

#Debugging....
#Write-Host $DB_NAME_MIRROR;
#Write-Host $STORAGE_URI_BACKUP;


#Database import
foreach ($DB in $DB_ARRAY) 
{
    $DB_NAME_IMPORT = $DB_NAME_MIRROR.Replace('<X>',$DB);
    $URL_FILE_BACKUP = $STORAGE_URI_BACKUP.Replace('<X>',$DB);
```